# SignalR Not Working with asp.net and sql server 2014

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, signalr

## SignalR With Asp.net MVC

Im trying since form 10 days but fail to solve my SignalR Issue.
Simply i want to show some data  using signalR,Here is my code
**

```
public List<User> Get()
        {
            List<User> user = new List<User>();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                string query = @"SELECT [Name],[Address] FROM [dbo].[UserTable]";
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                conn.Open();
                comm.Notification = null;
                SqlDependency dep = new SqlDependency(comm);
                dep.OnChange += Dep_OnChange;
                using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        User users = new User();
                        users.Name = reader[0].ToString();
                        users.Address = reader[1].ToString();
                        user.Add(users);
                    }
                }
            }
            return user;
private void Dep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                MyHub hub = new MyHub();
                hub.Send();
            }

        }
```

**
Controller Code:

```
 public JsonResult GetAll()
        {
            NotificationComponent dc = new NotificationComponent();
            var list = dc.Get();
            return new JsonResult { Data=list,JsonRequestBehavior=JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
        }
```

this returning a list of users but not Asynchronously (as expected).

My js Code is here.

```
<script>
        function getAll() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Home/GetAll',
                success: function (data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $('#get').append("<li>Name: " + data[i].Name + "Address: " + data[i].Address + "</li>");
                    }
                }
            })
        }

            $.connection.hub.start()
                .done(function () {
                    console.log("Hub Connected...");
                   
            })
       getAll();
            $.connection.myHub.client.notify = function () {
                getAll();
            }

    </script>
```

Sql Queries

```
GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO [NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE]
GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO [NT AUTHORITY\IUSR]
GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO [JANBAZ\JANBAZ KHAN]
ALTER DATABASE [SignalRDb] SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

this all i have done ,i think the query is problem,please help me
Thanks in advance
(VS 2017,IIS Version 10,Sql server2014,win 10)

Comment: What is your hub code?

Comment: public class MyHub:Hub
    {
        public void Send()
        {
            Clients.All.notify();
        }
    }